# PHP using string to point to a function

Tags: php, string, function

While searching for something else, I found this code

```
$x = "foo";
    function foo(){ echo "wtf"; }
$x(); # "wtf"
```

and when I searched google for this, I got only C results not PHP, while I know that under the PHP hood is C, I would really like some explanation about that.

What is that called?

and how it is interpreted by PHP zend? is it some sort of callable?

and is it still available in PHP 7+ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It is a callable (variable function: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php )
2. Zend just treats it as a callable and calls the function.
3. It is an old and stable language feature, and still available in PHP7+ (and it will be available as long as possible)

The callable types and normalizations are given in the table below:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php#118032

```
Callable                        | Normalization                   | Type
--------------------------------+---------------------------------+--------------
function (...) use (...) {...}  | function (...) use (...) {...}  | 'closure'
$object                         | $object                         | 'invocable'
"function"                      | "function"                      | 'function'
"class::method"                 | ["class", "method"]             | 'static'
["class", "parent::method"]     | ["parent of class", "method"]   | 'static'
["class", "self::method"]       | ["class", "method"]             | 'static'
["class", "method"]             | ["class", "method"]             | 'static'
[$object, "parent::method"]     | [$object, "parent::method"]     | 'object'
[$object, "self::method"]       | [$object, "method"]             | 'object'
[$object, "method"]             | [$object, "method"]             | 'object'
```

Comment: Thank you .. this is the line that I'm seeking to understand `A PHP function is passed by its name as a string.` under **Passing** section.

Answer (score 5):

This is called variable functions in PHP : http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php

Basically, when there is a variable before the `()`, first the variable get resolved and interpreter get the value of it and try to find the function with that value. If the function exists, it calls or function not found exception will be thrown.

Comment: This answer is a little light on details.  Could you perhaps expand on your answer?  Currently it looks more like a comment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however that didnt include Q2 thoroughly and Q3.

Answer (score 0):

A variable function. The variable x is simply holding a value which is equal to function name. Calling variable that way results to calling the function.